# Pass in strings received from another tableviewcontroller

Tags: swift, string, uitableview, nsobject, nscoding

I am building a quite simple product ordering app.
This is a tabbed application being, Product List, Order List and settings.
From the Product List (coredata parsed from remote csv file) I can search then select a row, which then pops an alert view to add desired quantity to textfield and then on "ADD" button in alertview I can segue with the four strings (Productcode, Detail, Quantity(from alertview) and barcode) to the Order List View controller. 
This is where im having trouble! 
I can print the four strings in console at the point of being recieved by OrderList, but I'm stuck for a way to pass those strings into My NSObject model in order to display and persist them in the labels of the tableviewcell.

Here is my OrderProduct.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class OrderProduct: NSObject, NSCoding {

var uuid: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
var productcode:String = ""
var detail:String = ""
var quantity:String = ""
var barcode:String = ""
var inOrderList = false

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(uuid, forKey: "uuid")
    coder.encodeObject(productcode, forKey: "productcode")
    coder.encodeObject(detail, forKey: "detail")
    coder.encodeObject(quantity, forKey: "quantity")
    coder.encodeObject(barcode, forKey: "barcode")
    coder.encodeBool(inOrderList, forKey: "inOrderList")
}
required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()

    if let archivedUuid = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("uuid") as? String {
        uuid = archivedUuid
    }

    if let archivedProductcode = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("productcode") as? String {
        productcode = archivedProductcode
    }

    if let archivedDetail = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("detail") as? String {
        detail = archivedDetail
    }

    if let archivedQuantity = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("quantity") as? String {
        quantity = archivedQuantity
    }

    if let archivedBarcode = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("barcode") as? String {
        barcode = archivedBarcode
    }

    inOrderList = decoder.decodeBoolForKey("inOrderList")
}
init(productcode: String, detail: String, quantity: String, barcode: String) {
    super.init()

    self.productcode = productcode
    self.detail = detail
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.barcode = barcode
}
}
```

And here is my OrderViewController.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//MARK: - Class
class TestOrderViewController: UITableViewController{

required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    //print("init OrderViewController")
    super.init(coder: decoder)

    loadOrderProducts()
    }

    deinit {
}

//MARK: - Product Vars
    var passedProductcode = String()     //String is recieved here!
    var passedDetail = String()          //String is recieved here!
    var passedQuantity = String()        //String is recieved here!
    var passedBarcode = String()         //String is recieved here!

    var orderProducts = [OrderProduct]() //My Object model...

//MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Order List"

    orderProducts.productcode = passedProductcode //Trying to pass them but
    orderProducts.detail = passedDetail           //errors with "Value of type
    orderProducts.quantity = passedQuantity       //'[OrderProduct]' has no
    orderProducts.barcode = passedBarcode         //member 'productcode'?

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return orderProducts.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderTableViewCell
    let orderProduct = orderProducts[indexPath.row]
    cell.productcodeLabel.text = orderProduct.productcode
    cell.detailLabel.text = orderProduct.detail
    cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(orderProduct.quantity)"
    cell.barcodeLabel.text = orderProduct.barcode

    return cell
}

private func loadOrderProducts() {
    if let filePath = pathForOrderProducts() where NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
        if let archivedOrderProducts = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as? [OrderProduct] {
            orderProducts = archivedOrderProducts
        }
    }
}

private func pathForOrderProducts() -> String? {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

    if let documents = paths.first, let documentsURL = NSURL(string: documents) {
        return documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("orderProducts.plist").path
    }
    return nil
}

private func saveOrderProducts() {
    if let filePath = pathForOrderProducts() {
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(orderProducts, toFile: filePath)
        }
    }
}
```

Could somebody please guide me to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `orderProducts` property in `TestOrderViewController` is an Array of `OrderProduct` so, when you try to do

```
cell.productcodeLabel.text = orderProducts.productcode //passedProductcode
cell.detailLabel.text = orderProducts.detail //passedDetail
cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(orderProducts.quantity/*passedQuantity*/)"
cell.barcodeLabel.text = orderProducts.barcode //passedBarcode
```

You're attempting to retrieve property-values on the array of `OrderProduct` rather than the instances inside it. It should *probably* be:

```
cell.productcodeLabel.text = orderProducts[indexPath.row].productcode //passedProductcode
cell.detailLabel.text = orderProducts[indexPath.row].detail //passedDetail
cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(orderProducts.quantity/*passedQuantity*/)"
cell.barcodeLabel.text = orderProducts[indexPath.row].barcode //passedBarcode
```

But you need to make sure your array contains the proper models (obviously).

---

OK, as promised I'll try to make a more complete example. This probably won't match your requirements 100% (which are note entirely clear to me anyway) but hopefully It'll get you on the way...

In the viewController where you are actually passing the values I would suggest that you rather pass an array of model-objects. This could be something like this:

```
struct ProductModel {
    var productcode: String
    var detail: String
    var quantity: String
    var barcode: String
}

var models = [ProductModel]()
```

So you'll crete instances of ProductModel and append these to the array. When you're ready to move to the next viewController `TestOrderViewController` by the looks of it you'll pass it the whole array (as it will have a matching property).
This will either be done before you push the viewController, or in prepareForSegue based on how you handle the viewControllers.

Then in `TestOrderViewController` you will have something like the below:

```
// UITableViewDataSource
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderTableViewCell
    let model = models[indexPath.row]
    cell.productcodeLabel.text = model.productcode
    cell.detailLabel.text = model.detail
    cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(model.quantity)"
    cell.barcodeLabel.text = model.barcode
    return cell
}
```

Comment: let orderProduct = orderProducts[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.productcodeLabel.text = orderProduct.productcode
        cell.detailLabel.text = orderProduct.detail
        cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(orderProduct.quantity)"
        cell.barcodeLabel.text = orderProduct.barcode

Comment: Thanks @T.Benjamin Larsen, my problem is really not with that end it is with passing the variables into the object in the first place. E.g var passedProductcode = String() how do I get that into orderProducts.productcode?

Comment: You can't. You `orderProducts` is _an array_ of `OrderProduct` it does NOT have any of those properties. You probably need to create a complete OrderProductInstance an add _this_ to the array. To my eyes those `passed...` properties doesn't seem to make all that much sense as they.

Comment: Geez, and I thought it would be a simple thing? Forget the OrderProduct array. All I really want to happen is to get the four passed... strings and pass them to the labels in a new cell and for that cell to "stay put" when I pass another cell in.. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not really, your dataSource needs to provide the data for all the cells you want to display, so if you need more than one cell you need to keep track of these. I don't think it's necessarily as hard as you might believe right now. It's probably just a question of sending complete models to the array rather than single properties to the viewController/dataSource...

Comment: Thank you for your patience with this, so let me get my (non-technical) head around this: At current my segue to orderViewController contains destination.passedProductcode = (selectedPC)! (+ 3 more) what you are saying is that I should be passing the selected strings into OrderProduct?

Comment: Not quite, what I'm saying is that rather than passing these single properties you should make a complete model-object `OrderProduct` _with_ these values. Then _this_ model should be added to the array the `TestOrderViewController` requires. You might set the whole array up in the viewController prior to this and pass the complete thing when you plan to move to the next view.

Comment: nope sorry cant get my head around it? Could you please help me with a basic example? My workflow goes like this: ProductTableViewController --> didSelectRowAtIndexPath --> UIAlertAction --> self.selectedPC = product.productcode! (+3 More) --> ADD button pressed performSegueWithIdentifier destination.passedProductcode = (selectedPC)! (+3 More) --> OrderViewController what would the model look like?

Comment: I have to earn my salary right now, but I'll have another look later today (early morning here).

Comment: Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it. Ive got much to learn...

Answer (score 0):

OK so I think I am making some progress, but am not quite there yet. Thank you T. Benjamin Larsen for your fantastic example.

I placed the following outside of the class on my ProductTableViewController (sending VC)

```
struct ProductModel {
var productcode: String
var detail: String
var quantity: String
var barcode: String
}

var models = [ProductModel]()

class ProductTableViewController: UITableViewController{
}
```

Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have the following:

```
var quantityTextField = UITextField()

let product = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ProductItem //--> Selected cell item.
var model = models[indexPath.row] //--> fatal error: Index out of range? How do I fix this?

        model.productcode = product.productcode! // --> This is the row data I want to send.
        model.detail = product.detail!
        model.quantity = quantityTextField.text!
        model.barcode = product.barcode!

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addProduct", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "addProduct" {
       print ("Add Item Segue!")
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! OrderViewController
            destination.selected = models
            }
      }
```

And in TestOrderVC I have:

```
class...
var selected = models

...numberOfRowsInSection
return selected.count

...cellForRowAtIndexPath

let model = selected[indexPath.row]
    cell.productcodeLabel.text = model.productcode
    cell.detailLabel.text = model.detail
    cell.quantityLabel.text = "X \(model.quantity)"
    cell.barcodeLabel.text = model.barcode
```

I am currently stuck with a fatal error.